# Access SQL Server global variable @@dbts via linked server, with database context

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a linked server (let's call it `FOOBAR`) setup. On that remote server, I have a database `BAZ`.

I need to access `FOOBAR`'s `@@DBTS` value for a particular database.

I can do this:

```sql
select dbts from OPENQUERY(FOOBAR, 'select @@dbts as dbts')
```

However, that'll give me the dbts for `master` (default) database. Not what I want.

I did find that I can also do this (though I've not tested it since the requirement, which I will get to, is a show-stopper):

```sql
exec [FOOBAR].[BAZ].[dbo].sp_executesql N'select @@dbts as dbts'
```

Unfortunately, this requires that I set `RPC OUT` to `true` - which is not an option for me.

So my question is: in SQL Server, how does one access a linked server's global variable, providing database context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from openquery(FOOBAR, 'exec(''use tempdb;select @@DBTS as dbts;'')')
```